# Joomla / Virturemart Product Image Overlay

Tags: php, jquery, css, joomla, virtuemart

I am using Joomla 3 on the template "Pajuh" the template comes with Virtuemart installed so decided to use this for the customers products, when you hover over a product image in the category you get an overlay, and once clicked this takes you to a large image of the product. I need to be able to change this so that when you click the product image you go to the "Product Details" page. I have tried everything to remove this overlay, but cannot find where to remove it!

This image shows the overlay on the product image1
[image]

I am sure this section of code at the bottom of the page is dealing with the overlay but I have no idea where to find it in the file structure to remove;

Section of code that is creating the overlay2
[image]

Any help on this would be awsome! If you have any questions about the problem please ask and I can provide more info.

Comment: embed your relevant code as a snippet, nobody is going to try zooming in and reading the code in that image